# How do I normalise dates in Tensorflow.js?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, linear-regression, tensorflow.js

I've been building some simple linear regression models in Tensorflow.js with various types of data sets. However, I would now like to see what the relationship is between dates and price in my dataset.

In previous models, I normalise the price or other features so that the tensor is expressed as a vector between 0 and 1.

How would one do this dates, where the first date would have to be 0 and the last date in the range 1? Furthermore I would need to denormalise the Tensor afterwards.

I can convert the date into a unix timestamp using a library like date.fns... but I wondered if there might be a cleaner way to do this.

My normalise and denormalise functions :

```js
        function normalise (tensor) {
            const min = tensor.min();
            const max = tensor.max();
            const normalisedTensor = tensor.sub(min).div(max.sub(min))
            return {
                tensor : normalisedTensor,
                min,
                max
            }
        }

        function denormalise(tensor, min, max) {
            const denormalisedTensor = tensor.mul(max.sub(min)).add(min);
            return denormalisedTensor    
        
        }
```

Comment: Dates of what exactly?

Comment: dates of transactions in this form '2021-03-21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic principle is that you need to convert the date formats (like `2021-03-21`) to numbers, then you can use the normalise and denormalise functions that you already have. In your solution you have done that, however, you can write it in a simpler way. You can use `date-fns`, but the standard JavaScript [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is also sufficient so I will use that.

Assuming your input is an array of date strings like `2021-05-01`, then you can do this:

```
const dateStrings = ['2021-05-01', '2021-05-07', '2021-05-31'];
const timestamps = dateStrings.map(dateString => new Date(dateString).valueOf());
const unnormalisedTensor = tf.tensor1d(timestamps);
```

Then you can use the functions you have for normalisation (and denormalisation).

You can convert back from timestamps to date strings like this:

```
const timestamps = await unnormalisedTensor.array();
const dateStrings = timestamps.map(timestamp => new Date(timestamp).toISOString().substring(0,10));
```

Comment: Thank you Justin, this does the trick perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by using date.fns to convert the dates into timestamps and then normalising with the following function

```js
const getTimestamps = (data) => {

    data.forEach(record => {
        let newDate = record.time
        newDate = new Date(newDate);
        const timestamp = getUnixTime(newDate);
        console.log(newDate, timestamp)
        record.timestamp = timestamp
    }
```